# How to set token after user provides email and password in angular

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I want to jwt authtentication using angular and here is my form and angular code to capture email and password:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="loginController"> 
<form method="post" ng-submit="loginForm()">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password">
    <div><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> keep me logged-in
    </label>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
myApp.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
{

$scope.email = "" ;
$scope.password = "" ;

$scope.loginForm = function(){
    alert("login controller called");
    console.log($scope.email);
    console.log($scope.password);
    var encodedString = 'email=' +
            encodeURIComponent($scope.email) +
            '&password=' +
            encodeURIComponent($scope.password);
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url: 'rs/loginResource',
        data: encodedString,
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    });
};
}]);
```

jersey Webservice:

```
@Path("/loginResource")
public class LoginResource {

@Context
private UriInfo context;
public LoginResource() {
}

@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password) 
{
    System.out.println("Email is: " + email);
    System.out.println("Password is: " + password);
}
```

And my question is

1. I don't want to send clear text password on http pipeline on submit
   and how do I secure it?
2. How to return a token from java servlet to client?

Doing some research showed header, payload and signature, but I have no idea how to implement this.

I am using java servlets(NOT SPRING) as backend. Can anyone please guide me. I have been trying from past days to make myself more confused.

Comment: We can't tell without knowing how your server provides the token, and expects you to provide it for subsequent requests.

Comment: @JBNizet I am planning to use `nimbus-jose-jwt` json web token of java

Comment: @JBNizet Here is the link: http://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt

Comment: @JBNizet So let me get it right. What my question is "I don't want to send the password in clear text" and how do I achieve it?

Comment: @JBNizet Updated my question

Comment: That seems to be a library to generate tokens. But it doesn't tell us how you send this token from the server to the frontend, and where the server expects to find the token in subsequent requests.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I am looking for. I am very new to this and also struggling in learning angular simultaneously. How do I send token from backend java servlet/webservice to front-end?

Comment: you can send it as a field of an object serialized to JSON, as the body of the response, as, I guess, you're doing with all your other backend services. But why don't you use a better tool to implement REST services? Spring-MVC or JAX-RS would be much better choices.

Comment: @JBNizet I am already using jersey at backend. Look at the updated question. So far I have in getting the username and password to backend and from here I don't know how to check against db and send a token back

Comment: Use JSON instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded: it will help in the backend and in the frontend (it's the default with angular). Instead of returning void, return a JavaBean that contains your token: it will be serialized as JSON by JAX-RS.

Comment: @JBNizet If I use json in front end instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded then I have to use some kind of json parser library in java to get the username and password. Is it worth it sending it in json?

Comment: That's integrated in JAX-RS. It transforms JSON to Java objects and vice-versa for you. You really need to read some documentation about what you're using.